# Unity Build Failure: A failure occured while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-cardboard, google-vr

[Build Failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWJ7C.jpg)
Hi! I always get this build failure whenever I try to build with the google cardboard XR plugin. I can build my project perfectly fine without the google cardboard XR plugin so I figured there was something wrong with the plugin or I did something wrong.

Here's what the console says:
[Console Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f7Tm.jpg)

Details of the 1st error:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\UnityEditorFolder\2020.3.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\UnityEditorFolder\2020.3.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\UnityEditorFolder\2020.3.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\UnityEditorFolder\2020.3.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-30\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\UnityEditorFolder\2020.3.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\UnityEditorFolder\2020.3.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\UnityEditorFolder\2020.3.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\UnityEditorFolder\2020.3.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\UnityEditorFolder\2020.3.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-30\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\UnityEditorFolder\2020.3.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only

Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig
Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues
Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources
Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues
Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources
Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease
Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease
Task :launcher:prepareLintJar
Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources
Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease
Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses
Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig
Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease
Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources
Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish
Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources
Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders
Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile
Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders
Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies
Task :launcher:sdkReleaseDependencyData
Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease

Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources
Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease
Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease
Task :launcher:processReleaseResources FAILED
Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJavaResource
Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies
37 actionable tasks: 37 executed

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)`
```

Details of 2nd error:

```
Note C:\Users\ADMIN\My project (3)\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:processReleaseResources'.
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\ADMIN.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:3:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_1000 not found.

 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:4:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_900 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:5:5-93: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_0 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:6:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_800 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:7:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_700 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:8:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_600 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:9:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_500 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:10:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_400 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:11:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_300 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:12:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_200 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:13:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_100 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:14:5-93: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_50 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:15:5-93: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_10 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:16:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_1000 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:17:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_900 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:18:5-101: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_0 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:19:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_800 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:20:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_700 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:21:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_600 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:22:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_500 not found.
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 32s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)``
```

Details of 3rd error:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
C:\Program Files\UnityEditorFolder\2020.3.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\UnityEditorFolder\2020.3.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[
Note: C:\Users\ADMIN\My project (3)\Temp\gradleOut\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:processReleaseResources'.
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\ADMIN.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:3:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_1000 not found.

 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:4:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_900 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:5:5-93: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_0 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:6:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_800 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:7:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_700 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:8:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_600 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:9:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_500 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:10:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_400 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:11:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_300 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:12:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_200 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:13:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_100 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:14:5-93: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_50 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:15:5-93: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_10 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:16:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_1000 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:17:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_900 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:18:5-101: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_0 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:19:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_800 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:20:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_700 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:21:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_600 not found.
     
 C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0ebba694f8e6a95bc427eaef4894530\material-1.6.1\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:22:5-102: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral2_500 not found.
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 32s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
stdout[
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\UnityEditorFolder\2020.3.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\UnityEditorFolder\2020.3.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\UnityEditorFolder\2020.3.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\UnityEditorFolder\2020.3.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-30\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\UnityEditorFolder\2020.3.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\UnityEditorFolder\2020.3.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\UnityEditorFolder\2020.3.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\UnityEditorFolder\2020.3.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\UnityEditorFolder\2020.3.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-30\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\UnityEditorFolder\2020.3.36f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only

Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig
Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues
Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources
Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues
Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources
Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease
Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease
Task :launcher:prepareLintJar
Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources
Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease
Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses
Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig
Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease
Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources
Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish
Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources
Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders
Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile
Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders
Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies
Task :launcher:sdkReleaseDependencyData
Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease

Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources
Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease
Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease
Task :launcher:processReleaseResources FAILED
Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJavaResource
Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies
37 actionable tasks: 37 executed
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <544f727be82940559155d775b51cba8c>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <544f727be82940559155d775b51cba8c>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <544f727be82940559155d775b51cba8c>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <544f727be82940559155d775b51cba8c>:0) UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action1[T] progress) (at <544f727be82940559155d775b51cba8c>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <544f727be82940559155d775b51cba8c>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <544f727be82940559155d775b51cba8c>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <544f727be82940559155d775b51cba8c>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <544f727be82940559155d775b51cba8c>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <544f727be82940559155d775b51cba8c>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <544f727be82940559155d775b51cba8c>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <544f727be82940559155d775b51cba8c>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <786b546700bc48b68852821de5e46ca9>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)`
```

I've tried switching unity editor versions, reimporting the google cardboard XR Plugins and followed the quickstart https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/unity/quickstart, and reinstalled the android build support but nothing happened and I still get the same errors.

Comment: I would try to narrow down the problem a bit. First make sure the pathname to your project has no spaces in it and only uses alphanumeric characters, If it still fails then make a brand new empty project and try to build that. If that works try adding any plugins you're using one at a time to the empty project. Keep going until you find where it breaks.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).